# I want to get more than two targets in output of model machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I want to get two classes in the prediction of the classification model with text.

```
model_RandomForest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,criterion='gini', random_state=0)
```

if I can add a parameter of number output

Comment: "more than two targets" versus "I want to get two classes" - the difference suggests that you do not consider "targets" and "classes" as synonyms. Is this intentional? If so, what is the difference between your definitions? But a Random Forest is just a forest of decision trees. The outcome is whatever value you put in the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi-label samples, you just need to define the class labels as a 2d numpy array.

Example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

X = np.random.rand(10,3)
y = np.random.rand(10,2)
y[y>0.7] = 1
y[y<=0.7] = 0

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Predict the multi-class labels:

```
clf.predict(X[:5,:])

array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.]])
```

In `sklearn`, this is known as `multilabel-indicator`.

> ‘multilabel-indicator’: y is a label indicator matrix, an array of two
> dimensions with at least two columns, and at most 2 unique values.